# Zend Framework Using fetch() statement in a loop, internal query doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, while-loop, fetch

I can't solve this one.

I have multiple while, and the one inside fetch only the first result and stop ...

Here is the code :

$categories is an array

```
array(18) {
  [0] => array(7) {
["category_id"] => string(1) "1"
["category_name"] => string(5) "pizza"
["category_display"] => string(5) "pizza"
["category_active"] => string(1) "1"
["category_parent"] => string(1) "0"
["category_position"] => string(1) "1"
["category_user_discount"] => string(2) "50"
}
[1] => array(7) {
["category_id"] => string(1) "2"
["category_name"] => string(4) "menu"
["category_display"] => string(4) "menu"
["category_active"] => string(1) "1"
["category_parent"] => string(1) "0"
["category_position"] => string(1) "2"
["category_user_discount"] => string(2) "30"
}
}

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT sell_id FROM sell WHERE sell.sell_status = 'close' AND sell_period_id >= '".$liste[0]."' AND sell_period_id <= '".$liste[1]."' ");

foreach ($categories as $cat)
{
    while ($sell2 = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        $stmt2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM sellcart WHERE sellcart_status = 'close' AND sellcart_sell_id =  '".$sell2['sell_id']."' ");

        while ($sellitem = $stmt2->fetch())
        {
            echo $sellitem['sellcart_item_category'];
        }
    }
}
```

The first loop is OK, but it doesn't loop into the second $cat ...

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Well obvious question, the SQL is returning more than one result?  Might need to debug a bit more to get help here.

Comment: Yes, of course, but thanks for asking ... I think there is a link that is lost when there are two fetch, but I can't find how to fix it.
Of course, I could use a fetchAll, but the datas are too large, and take too much memory, that's why I wish to use fetch()...

Answer (score 0):

I know is too late for an answer but, the problem is, after the second fetch php close the connection or has no more values for the first fetch and return false. Maybe can you try out with a second connection for the second fetch.

Sorry for my English.

```
// for example ..............
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config["database"]["adapter"],$config["database"]        ["params"]);
$db2 = $db = Zend_Db::factory($config["database"]["adapter"],$config["database"]["params"]);
//  .......
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT sell_id FROM sell WHERE sell.sell_status = 'close' AND sell_period_id >= '".$liste[0]."' AND sell_period_id <= '".$liste[1]."' ");

foreach ($categories as $cat) {
    while ($sell2 = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $stmt2 = $db2->query("SELECT * FROM sellcart WHERE sellcart_status = 'close' AND sellcart_sell_id =  '".$sell2['sell_id']."' ");

        while ($sellitem = $stmt2->fetch()) {
            echo $sellitem['sellcart_item_category'];
        }
    }
}
```